# Arangodb, how to create edges that have additional info

Tags: java, arangodb, nosql

I am writing an application in Java using ArangoDB as database. I have a graph, and vertices. I can create PlainEntityEdges, but my question is how do i store more information in edges. For e.g, I have two vertices Image that are related to each other. The edge should store a pair of coordinates (it can be JSON {"x":"10", "y":"15"}). Can this be done using the Java Driver, if yes how? Are there other options for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
EdgeEntity<?> edge = ArangoDriver.graphCreateEdge( graphName, collectionName, null, sorceHandler, destinationHandler, new Postions(x, y), null);
```